# How to get the mouse button pressed from a command event in XUL?

Tags: javascript, xul

It seems that the XUL *command* and *click* events are somewhat different.

Although my function does get called when using the *command* event, the event object does not contain the *button* property.

My question is: **how do I detect what mouse button that was pressed without using the *click* event?**

The simplest code that can demonstrate my problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>

<window id="yourwindow" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
<script language="JavaScript">
    var showMeTheButton=function(e)
    {
        alert(e.button);
    }
</script>
<button onclick="showMeTheButton(event)" label="Click me with onclick"></button>
<button oncommand="showMeTheButton(event)" label="Click me with oncommand"></button>
</window>
```

Answer (score 2):

The main thing to keep in mind is that `oncommand` is fired for any action that results in an activation of the button which can include pressing the space bar when the button has the focus, using a keyboard shortcut attached to the button, or clicking the button with the mouse. The event handler is not really supposed to care how it was called, only that it was. (I imagine this was a conscious decision to keep a consistent user interface.)

The only actions that result in the button property being added to the Event object are  `onclick`, `ondblclick`, `onmousedown`, and `onmouseup`. You'll note that even if you disable your `onclick` button, the event still fires whereas with `oncommand` it won't.

To get the same functionality as `oncommand`, you'd need to handle both `onclick` and `onkeydown` events yourself while making sure the button is still enabled. You also might be able to create a custom button using XBL which have custom events like `onleftclick` or `onmiddleclick` that then fall back to `oncommand` if they are not set--but I've not tried it.